# Inverse Laplace transform to obtain the dynamical equation for a vairiable?

Tags: laplace-transform

Given an equation for $Y(s)$ and $X(s)$
$$
\frac{Y(s)}{1-sY(s)} = \frac{1}{\omega^2} X(s) - \frac{1}{\omega},
$$
where $Y(s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-st}y(t)dt$, $X(s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-st}x(t)dt$ are Laplace transforms of dynamical variables $y(t)$ and $x(t)$. Initially, $y(0) =1$. I want to obtain the equation of $y(t)$ in terms of $x(t)$.

Here is what I did.

Solution: Rewrite the equation as
$$
Y(s) = \frac{1}{\omega^2} X(s) [1-sY(s)] - \frac{1}{\omega} [1-sY(s)].
$$
Because $y(0)=1$, therefore,
$$
Y(s) = -\frac{1}{\omega^2} X(s) [sY(s)-y(0)] + \frac{1}{\omega} [sY(s)-y(0)].
$$
Perform inverse Laplace transform for both sides of the above equation,
$$
y(t) = -\frac{1}{\omega^2}\int_0^t d\tau \ x(t-\tau)\frac{dy(\tau)}{d\tau} +\frac{1}{\omega} \frac{dy(t)}{dt}.
$$
Then I obtain the equation of $y(t)$ in terms of $x(t)$:
$$
\frac{dy(t)}{dt} = \omega y(t) + \frac{1}{\omega}\int_0^t d\tau \ x(t-\tau)\frac{dy(\tau)}{d\tau}.
$$
My question: I am not sure if the procedure or the final equation is correct. Could you please give suggestions about my solution or is there other methods to obtain the equation of $y(t)$?

Comment: Perhaps you could do it formally. Multiply the equation by $\omega^2 (1-xY)$ and solve for $Y$ to get something like $Y = {X-\omega \over s(X-\omega) + \omega^2}$.

Comment: @copper.hat After I solve the $Y$ as you suggested, I also have to express $y(t)$ by $x(t)$. Could you tell me how or is it possible to obtain the same dynamical equation (if correct, as I obtained) for $y(t)$ from the expression $Y = \frac{X-\omega}{s(X-\omega)+\omega^2}$?

Comment: Ignore my comment, it is not helpful.

Comment: Your equation looks fine to me. You can check by just taking the transform again.